# tree from string

Tags: atomic-code-golf

A string like this one:

"a, 4.25, ((true, 5), 3, (false, false, false)), abc"

Describes a tree with 13 nodes, 9 of which are leaf nodes. In C# the leaf nodes in this example would be of types `string`, `float` and `bool`, this differs between languages and depending on your implementation. The important structure forming symbols here are `,` `(` and `)` with spaces being ignored.

See the diagram in David Carrahers answer for a tree of the desired shape.

```
var a = new cake(4, "abc")
```

The above contains 8 symbols, I'm counting bracket and `"` pairs as a half and things like `.` as 1.

The goal is to write code with the fewest symbols which given a string like the one shown above, creates the tree it represents.

For example in the form of arrays inside each other, or interconnecting node objects.

60 extra points if you don't sort of cheat by adjusting the input string slightly then executing it.

I won't count the symbols that define the input string.

```
daniero
100 - (10 symbols)
+40 points for understanding numbers, strings, bools
    and any other basic types the language understands.
+20 points for using a reasonably general language.
150 total points

fejesjoco
100 - (est 37 symbols)
+20 points for it understanding numbers as well as strings.
+40 points for using a reasonably general language.
97 total points

tomas
100 - (10 symbols)
90 total points

David Carraher
100 - (est 19 symbols)
81 total points
```

Comment: Looks like homework, basic tokenizing as part of writing a script interpreter.

Comment: Please define the exact syntax of the string.

Comment: I only see 12 nodes, can you explain it a bit better?

Comment: @TeunPronk I guess the 13th is the root node.

Comment: The 13th node is the root, although this dosn't matter greatly. It's not homework or a part of a course.

Comment: Why don't you give examples of the output you are expecting?

Comment: *"[...] creates **the** tree it represents."* There are a lot of ways to form a tree out of a list. What defines a token (i.e. are your stings comma and space delimited, and why two delimitters)? What imposes structure on the tree (i.e are the parenthesis intended to indicate sub-trees)? Is the tree expected to be binary? This is very weakly specified, and consequently is not going to generate a very interesting set of responses. You can get help with these kinds of problems in chat or by posting to one of the [meta sand-boxes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/954/).

Comment: The question now has more detail. Now I'd like to see your solution dmckee :)

Comment: How is "adjusting input string" cheating? How is using symbols a bad thing? I don't understand the purpose of this challenge any more. It started as a good question but then you spoiled it with nonsense - and changed rules on the run! Retracting my upvote and -1!

Comment: Symbols is equivalent to characters, see the description for the atomic-code-golf tag, most challenges here are for short code. And a solution like "s.toTree();" where "s" is the input string is not really a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
s="a, 4.25, ((true, 5), 3, (false, false, false)), abc"
eval(("["+s+"]").replace(/\(/g,"[").replace(/\)/g,"]").replace(/([a-z]+)/g,"'$1'"))
```

The exact syntax, input and output format weren't exactly defined... I replace every a-z character to become a string, even true/false, which could be booleans, but there's no indication if there should be a distinction. I don't know if other characters are allowed or not (ő, $, \uFA20, ...), so my code doesn't care about that either.

Comment: I tried it in the Firebug console in Firefox. Also works in the developer console of IE.

Comment: The result is a recursive array: `["a", 4.25, [["true", 5], 3, ["false", "false", "false"]], "abc"]`

Comment: It may be bit of cheating, but it's the most straightforward way I can imagine. Writing a parser is a big task, but many languages have eval-like functions, so there's a reusable parser right there.

Comment: Oh, you replace some of the brackets in the string with another type then execute the string :P Impressive all the same :) You may win, particularly if no less cheaty solutions are posted.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica

`StringReplace` replaces all instances of `(` with `List[`; instances of  `)` with `]`.

The FullForm of `List` must be used (instead of `{…}`); otherwise `ToExpression` will not parse the string correctly.

```
f@t_:=ToExpression["List["<>StringReplace[t,{"("->"List[",")"->"]"}]<>"]"]
```

---

**Example**

```
f["a, 4.25, ((true, 5), 3, (false, false, false)), abc"]
```

> {a, 4.25, {{true, 5}, 3, {false, false, false}}, abc}

---

**Verification**

`TreeForm[<expression>]` displays the Mathematica expression as a tree.

```
TreeForm[f["a, 4.25, ((true, 5), 3, (false, false, false)), abc"]]
```

[image: tree form]

Answer (score 2):

## R, 36 chars

```
plot(read.tree(,paste0("(",a,");")))
```

package ape must be loaded.

#### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp

I *think* it would count as something around 11 symbols?

Wrap parentheses around the string, remove the commas and evaluate it, and you have a LISP list.

```
(read-from-string (remove #\, (concatenate 'string "(" s ")" )))
```

`s` is the string.

For the given example it returns a list `(A 4.25 ((TRUE 5) 3 (FALSE FALSE FALSE)) ABC)`

Comment: For those not familiar with lisp, it would be helpful to know that the internal representation of s-expressions *is* a tree. By striping the commas daniero has rendered the input into a s-expression. Then he just internalizes it and *::Bingo!::*